# Impedir que redirecione para outra página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirecionamento

Boa Tarde.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é que quando o usuário clicar em um item do menu, ele carregue o arquivo que contem um form dentro da "Outra página".
Até o momento isso acontece, o problema vem depois. 
Quando clico no botão do formulário que é carregado ele redireciona para a página do php que salva os dados no banco, por isso, tanto o menu, quanto o aside somem.
O objetivo é que ele permaneça na mesma página, ou que se redirecione, seja só dentro da área da "Outra Página".
Procurando na internet achei que deveria usar ajax, mas não deu.

O Ajax está assim

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btCadastrar').click(function(){
    var nome= $('#txtnome').val();
   var cpf = $('#txtcpf').val();
   var senha = $('#txtsenha').val();
   var nivel = $('#selectNivel').val();
   $('form').submit(function(){
     $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"cadusuarios.php",
    data:{"nome":nome, "cpf":cpf,"senha":senha,"nivel":nivel},
    error: function(){
      alert("Erro ao Cadastrar");
       }
      });
     });
    });
   });
</script>
```

E no PHP está assim:

```html
 <?php
  include "conexao.php";
  
  $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome');
  $cpf  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf');
  $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha');
  $nivel = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nivel');
  
  /*
  $nome=utf8_encode($_POST['txtnome']);
  $cpf=utf8_encode($_POST['txtcpf']);
  $senha=utf8_encode($_POST['txtsenha']);
  $nivel=($_POST['nivel']);
  */
  session_start();
  try 
  {
   $sql= "Select nome,cpf,senha from c_usuarios where nome='$nome' and cpf='$cpf' and senha='$senha' ";
   $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($rs)>0)
   {
    $_SESSION['cadastrado']='Usuário Já Cadastrado';
    header('Location:Cadastrarusuarios.php');
   }
   else
   {
    $sql = "Insert into c_usuarios(nome,cpf,senha,nivel)values('$nome','$cpf','$senha','$nivel')";
    $rs=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   }
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
   return $e->getMessage();
  }
  finally
  {
   mysqli_close($conn);
  }
 ?>
```

OBS: Sou leigo em ambos, então peço desculpas se estiver muito ruim, mas é para um trabalho de faculdade, onde junto de mais alguns colegas fui encarregado do desenvolvimento.

Comment: vc está usando action no form? Com o ajax não precisa de usar a action, se não ele vai redirecionar mesmo

Comment: Estava, mas agora mudei e deu certinho. Muito Obrigado